# Debug external libaries in Rider IDE

Tags: debugging, external, rider

In Visual Studio 2015 I can debug an external library very easy if I have the source code. I just open a source code file of that library in VS and set breakpoints, then I just need to load the assembly (or module) in the view "Modules" where I can right on the external library and select "Load Symbols" (and as well "Always Load Symbols" if required).

Now the breakpoints set in the external library work.

How can I achieve the same in the Rider IDE? Is is possible at all to debug external libraries with Rider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is not supported in Rider so far but planned for 2017.3. [Here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-10383) is an issue on JetBrains Youtrack to watch and vote for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Actually it is now implemented it seems. @Julia maybe you want to update the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The feature has been available by default since the 2017.3.1 (173.3994.2442) version of the Rider.

> External-source debugging is enabled by default. If you want the debugger to ignore library code, you can disable it.

You can also set breakpoints in decompiled code:

> To navigate to symbols in external code from your source code, you can use almost all of the navigation and search features — if the navigation target is in a library code, JetBrains Rider will automatically decompile and display it in the editor. The easiest way to jump to library code is to Ctrl-click any usage of a library symbol or press F12.

If you encountered problems with debugging external symbols, you may remove decompilation cache at the `%USERPROFILE%\.Rider2023.2\config\resharper-host\DecompilerCache` (use your Rider version).

Read more at:

- [Debug external code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Debugging_External_Code.html) (Rider help)
- [Debugging third-party code with Rider](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/12/20/debugging-third-party-code-rider/) (JetBrains blog)

Answer (score -1):

you can replace lib dll in your solution with dll from lib source.

Here is an example: [How to debug OrchardCore source code in an existing project](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/discussions/10603) .

Orchard Core is an open source and can be used in your .net project. you can run your project and orchard core official project, then attach you project in oc.

Comment: Please don't stump your personal projects as an unrelated parts of answers

Comment: @aaronburro  its personal project, but its method is not.

Answer (score -2):

- In Rider settings disable the checkbox: "Do not step into library scripts".
- If you have access to the source code, generate a nuget package including symbols. (for netcore cli: dotnet pack -o "../myNugetPackages --include-symbols --version-suffix "-localversion"
- Adjust your nuget.config package resource to get files from local directory: 
  `<add key="local-packages" value="../myNugetPackages" />`
- Add the local package version as dependency in your project that is opened by Rider.
- Open files from the source code (used to generate the package) and add breakpoints.